# FacesContext: separate error and success messages

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm creating error messages this way:

```
public static void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(errorMessage));
}
```

and showing them on the form in case of error (red color):

```
<h:messages styleClass="error"/>
```

How to separate error and success messages in JSF? Simply, how to show the positive messages in green color and the negativ in red?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `errorClass` and `infoClass` attributes instead to specify different style classes for those severities (there are also `warnClass` and `fatalClass`, see also [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html)):

```html
<h:messages infoClass="info" errorClass="error" />
```

The `styleClass` covers the unmatched severities. You only need to change the way how you created the message. When you don't specify the severity, it defaults to "info". See also [the `FacesMessage` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html).

```
public static void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, null));
}
```